# Can't see last 10 days battery usage

Tags: mac, battery, apple-silicon

In battery usage I can only see the last 24 hours battery usage and not the last 10 days battery usage.

Is there any way to figure out what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: I assume you actually did you use your Mac during that period and didn't do any kind of reset/reinstall yesterday?

Comment: Nope. No reset no reinstall. Used it.